# Swift could not start

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-swift

While installing Swift on my machine (ubuntu), I got an error on the last step. Swift starts normally as shows the following picture.

[image]

Then, I got this error : 
[image]

Can I anyone help me to solve this issue ??

Thank you,

Comment: Can you share your proxy-server.conf config file and also share the output of `cat /etc/passwd`